# how to parse image base64 and jpeg from json using picasso

Tags: android, json, android-studio, picasso

i'm trying to parse an image which is base64 or jpeg. i'm trying to parse base64 first with this code

```
if(ar.has("foto"))
                    {
                        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(ar.getString("foto", Base64.DEFAULT));
                       Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                    }
```

but it says `getString (String) in JSONObject cannot be applied to (String, int)` which is `int` in red line. 
it says error in this line of code `("foto", Base64.DEFAULT)` . please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

from :

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(ar.getString("foto", Base64.DEFAULT));
```

to :

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(ar.getString("foto"),  Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: do you know how when it also can parse jpeg?

Comment: I don't understand your query. please describe in details.